# Error: (E107) bind interface to port failed: type mismatch on port 4 of module `simple_instance.data_in_reg'

Tags: c++, systemc

i want to read bus in register_out and write to bus in register_in but i get type mismatch error on port4 of register_in

Register.hpp file

```
#pragma once
#include<systemc.h>
#include"bus.hpp"
class Register:public sc_module{
private:
  sc_port<sc_signal_in_if<sc_logic>> clk,rst,lden;
  sc_port<sc_signal_in_if<sc_lv<8>>> in_load;
  sc_port<sc_signal_write_if<sc_lv<8>>> out;

public:
  SC_CTOR(Register){
    SC_METHOD(eval);
    sensitive<<clk<<rst;
  }
void eval(){
    if(rst->read()=='1')
        out->write(0);
    else if(clk->event() && clk->read()=='1')
        out->write(in_load->read());
  }
};
```

test_module head file

```
#pragma once  
#include<systemc.h>
#include"Register.hpp"
class test_module:public sc_module{
  sc_port<sc_signal_in_if<sc_logic>> clk,rst,lden_in,lden_out;
  sc_port<sc_signal_in_if<sc_lv<8>>> data_in;
  sc_port<sc_signal_write_if<sc_lv<8>>> data_out;
  sc_port<sc_signal_inout_if<sc_lv<8>>> bus; 

public:
  Register  *data_in_reg,*data_out_reg;
  SC_CTOR(test_module){
    data_in_reg=new Register("data_in_reg");
      (*data_in_reg)(clk,rst,lden_in,data_in,bus); // ERROR  
    data_out_reg=new Register("data_out_reg");
      (*data_out_reg)(clk,rst,lden_out,bus,data_out);
   }
 };
```

Comment: Have you tried reading from `register_in` and writing to `register_out`? Just in case you got them the wrong way round

Comment: I cant bind sc_inout_if to the register output port

Comment: It may help if you copy and paste the complete/exact error message you are getting.

Comment: when i run program i got this from systemc

SystemC 2.3.2-Accellera --- May 22 2021 13:45:11
        Copyright (c) 1996-2017 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
Warning: (W506) illegal characters: simple instance substituted by simple_instance
In file: ../../../src/sysc/kernel/sc_object.cpp:247

Error: (E107) bind interface to port failed: type mismatch on port 4 of module `simple_instance.data_in_reg'
In file: ../../../src/sysc/kernel/sc_module.cpp:570'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i replace **sc_port<sc_signal_in_if>** to **sc_in** and **sc_port<sc_signal_write_if>** to **sc_out** and make bus to **sc_inout** and it's work.
but i have question why this way work but by using sc_port and interface i got mismatch error